# get ALL tweets of a specific location

Tags: twitter

I would like to get all tweets (or at least a representative sample) from one location.

For "all" english tweets, I made something like that in python:

requests.post('https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json', data={'track': 'http,is,it,on,in,a,the,of,I,for,this,at,my,to,your,do,have,has,does'}, auth=oauth, stream=True)

But how to filter on location at the request time ?

Note taht I can filter after, on receiving tweets, by selecting the 'location' key in the dictionary, but by doing this, I will get a very restricted set of tweet for a location because twitter limits the number of tweets you are receiving from a resquest : That the reason why I have to build the right request to stream directly the right tweets : But how to do this for a specific location ??

Comment: Are you building another PRISM? ;-)

Comment: Do you mean the location of the **user** (according to their profile), or the location of the **tweet**. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

v1.1 of the [`POST statuses/filter`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter) API seems to have a [locations](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#locations) parameter. Have you tried it?

Comment: it works only on geolocated tweets, and it does not care of the "location" tweet field which is user filled.